# arduino aJSON library valuefloat always returns 0.00

Tags: json, arduino

```
  aJsonObject* sBoard = aJson.createObject();
  aJsonObject* sensorType = aJson.createObject();

  aJsonObject* sBoard = aJson.createObject();
  aJsonObject* sensorType = aJson.createObject();

  aJson.addItemToObject(sBoard, "name", aJson.createItem("SensorBoardOne"));
  aJson.addItemToObject(sBoard, "Sensor", sensorType);

  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "ph", 5.33);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "ec", 880);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "temp", 74.68);

  aJsonObject* ph = aJson.getObjectItem(sensorType, "ph");

  Serial.println(ph->valuefloat);
```

`Serial.println(ph->valuefloat);` returns 0.00. I have never dealt with C structs before and not sure if I setup the syntax correctly. My json structure seems fairly straight forward; however, I am not sure if I am accessing the correct creatObject() for the ph float value.  What should I do to get the proper value of ph?

For further information about the aJSON library, please visit: http://interactive-matter.eu/blog/2010/08/14/ajson-handle-json-with-arduino/

**EDIT new code:**

```
  aJsonObject* sBoard = aJson.createObject();
  
  aJson.addItemToObject(sBoard, "name", aJson.createItem("SensorBoardOne"));
  
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sBoard, "ph", 5.33);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sBoard, "ec", 880);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sBoard, "temp", 74.68);
  
  aJsonObject* phValue = aJson.getObjectItem(sBoard, "ph");
  char* string = aJson.print(sBoard);
    if (string != NULL) {
      Serial.println(string); //prints out: {"name":"SensorBoardOne","ph":5.33000,"ec":880,"temp":74.68000}

    }

  Serial.println(phValue->valuefloat);
```

I ended up changing the json structure to more of a simpler structure.  I felt there wasn't a need for a another substructure due to the ram shortage of the arduino.  After shortening the json structure I was able to successfully get the valuefloat of ph.  I am still interested in figuring out the prior issue for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code and found that you have declared both sBoard and sensorType twice at the beginning of the snippet.

I removed it and I am getting the proper response "5.33". This is the code that I am using after editing.

```
  aJsonObject* sBoard = aJson.createObject();
  aJsonObject* sensorType = aJson.createObject();

  aJson.addItemToObject(sBoard, "name", aJson.createItem("SensorBoardOne"));
  aJson.addItemToObject(sBoard, "Sensor", sensorType);

  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "ph", 5.33);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "ec", 880);
  aJson.addNumberToObject(sensorType, "temp", 74.68);

  aJsonObject* ph = aJson.getObjectItem(sensorType, "ph");

  Serial.println(ph->valuefloat);
```